# Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic (Bignum) for 16-bit processor

Tags: embedded, bignum, 16-bit, 8051, arbitrary-precision

I'm developing an application for a 16-bit embedded device (80251 microcontroller), and I need arbitrary precision arithmetic. Does anyone know of a library that works for the 8051 or 80251?

GMP doesn't explicitly support the 8051, and I'm wary of the problems I could run into on a 16-bit device.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered writing these operations yourself.  The fact that your are wary of problems on a 16-bit device makes me think that Add and Multiply would be fairly easy for you.  Mod is a little bit more work but still doable.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this one](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/392/programs/bignum.c).  Or, give us an idea of what you're trying to do with it; understanding the workload would help a lot. [TTMath](http://www.ttmath.org/faq) looks promising. Or, there are approximately a zillion of them listed in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

Comment: I'm trying to implement some basic crypto on a 16-bit processor. Obviously speed is not important, but I need to be able to work with numbers in the range of say, 128 to 2048 bits. So I actually *don't* need arbitrary precision, but something that can handle 2048 bits at least. I'd also settle for an 8-bit library. I had checked out several from the Wiki, but none of them appeared to be compatible with a 251. Thanks for your response, I'll check out your suggestions.

Comment: I suppose I should mention which operations are critical: add, mul, and mod are mandatory. div and floating point support are not necessary.

Comment: Go for a pure-C library then.  Minor twiddling of the size declarations should work out.  Honestly, a bignum implementation shouldn't be very sensitive to word size as long as you aren't trying to optimize heavily.